# CSS Centering a div in different Screens

Tags: html, css

I am wondering if the div in this css and html will stay at the center if I i view this site on a larger screen. since I am only working on a 16 inch screen/ monitor. will the div in this code will stay at the center even if I move or view it in a larger/different screen? ?

The Html

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Midterm Practice</title>
  <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "layout.css"/>
 </head>
  <body>
    <div id = "container">
      <div id = "navbar">
        <ul>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The CSS rules

```
body{background-color: pink;}
#container{background-color: white;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;border: 1px solid white;border-radius: 15px;width: 1000px;height: 800px;}
#navbar{position:absolute;}
```

I am just starting out with CSS please don't add advance or above average answers

Comment: yes.. but `#navbar` should not have absolute position if `#container` does not have absolute or relative position and you want it inside the container..

Comment: why shouldn't the navbar be in absolute position? and yes I do plan placing inside the container.

Comment: You probably don't need the navbar to be absolute, but if that is what you really need to do then the container should have a relative position that the navbar will be positioned absolute to. I suspect you do not need this though and can just float the navbar within the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` should have the desired effect for you. They will basically centre the "container" div in the body tag. You could always test it out yourself by reducing the width of the container to something you can test in your browser (Chrome and Firefox's dev tools are useful for playing with CSS within the browser).

Comment: Not if you apply position: absolute to the container div. Absolute is for specifying the position within the containing markup, so basically setting the coordinate of a corner of the element.

Comment: you could use absolute positioning with negative left-margin (width / 2) ... auto margin is better