# how to position a container in the middle of the screen?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS Centering a div in different Screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377099/css-centering-a-div-in-different-screens)

I presume the answer to this question is really simple but i am stumped.

I am trying to get a website positioned in the center of the screen like the Guardian website - http://www.guardian.co.uk/.  I assumed i was right to use a left and right border, however this has made positioning the footer difficult.

Having looked at the guardian website and using the firefox inspect element capability it appears they are using no divs on the left and right of the screen whatsoever.  In fact there container appears to just be in the middle of the screen.

So i suppose my question is.  How do you position a container like so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
.container {
    /* remember to set a width */
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d9yBs/

---

You can also combine to 2 margin properties, and use the shorthand:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

This'll set the top & bottom margin to 0, and the left & right to auto.

Comment: thats the correct way, position:relative is very important using margin- ...

Answer (score 3):

quick way is:

```
#container
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: -100px /* half of you height */
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: -200px /* half of you width */
}
```

another way for only centering only is

```
#container
{
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="page_wrap">
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.page_wrap
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
body
{
    text-align: center; /* required by some browsers */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pc7AY/ check it out.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a trick with CSS:

`margin: 0 auto;`

From the guardian site:

```
div.InSkinAlignCenter {
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

As far as I remember `position` property should be set to `relative`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

CSS:

```
.page {
    width: 200px;
    background: #FF0000;
    margin: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="page">
    This is the content.
</div>
```

Also, check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ErRAr/)!